How to increase distance by a unit after every instance in Geometric Nodes array?
Suppose I have an array with four instances. And they have a constant distance between them right now, say N units. I want the distance to increase by M unit after every instance. So, distances will be like N, N+M, N+2M, N+3M ...
Interestingly, I could achieve similar thing with the scale value by applying some math nodes and index to "Scale" input of "Instance on Points". But there's no distance/offset input in that node so I couldn't do it.
I tried following highlighted approach, but it still gave me constant distance.


You can use "Accumulate Field" node for that:

In this case you can also use maths:
$$Δx = N + i×(i-1)×{1 \over 2} × M$$


It worked. May I know why the "logic" I used didn't work? (It didn't work even when I moved node right after Mesh Line just like you). From what I understand, what my logic is doing is, you get 1, 2, 3, 4... from Index node for each instance respectively, then you multiply it with some number (so for every index, it will keep increasing) and give it to offset of Set Position. I might be wrong here but I don't know why.

@Vikas well, the math is wrong :P you're increasing the distance but not accumulating it. If you graph it, you will see the calculated value grows linearly, not exponentially.
